# PHP SDK - How to check in facebook profile user if post exists?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm posting in my users Facebook with this code:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

i want to know if the user remove manually that post, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

After the submission you got the post id. You can use this id with client access token to check the status.

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: i don't have the ACCESS_TOKEN, how i can find it ?